# Topology - Product space example

Tags: general-topology

In the book "Topology" from Boto von Querenburg I read the following example for product spaces:

"The product space of a circumference and an interval $[a,b]$ with $0<a<b$ is homeomorphic to the annulus $\left\lbrace (x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 \colon b \geq x^2+y^2 \geq a \right\rbrace$."

I think this statement looks evident by intuition. But how can I see this by formal calculating?

Comment: circumference = circle? In that case we get a cylinder, not an annulus..

Comment: @HennoBrandsma same thing (in this case).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider $f:\left\lbrace (x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 \colon a \geq x^2+y^2 \geq b \right\rbrace \rightarrow S^1\times[a,b] $ that sends $(x,y)$ to $((\frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}},\frac{y}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}),\sqrt{x^2+y^2})$. Verify that $f$ is a continuous bijection and use the following theorem after proving it:

Fact: Let $X,Y$ be compact Hausdorff spaces. If $f:X\rightarrow Y$ is a continuous bijection, then it is a homeomorphism.

Comment: You can drop Hausdorff-ness on $X$ and compactness on $Y$ and it's still true.

Comment: @kahen Yes. I just wanted to type less. ${}{}{}{}$

Answer (score 4):

The same way you always show spaces to be homeomorphic: By exhibiting a homeomorphism.

You may find the following helpful:

**The Greatest Trick of Elementary Topology (GTET):** A continuous bijection from a compact space to a Hausdorff space is a homeomorphism.

Answer (score 0):

Let $A=\{(x,y)\in\mathbb R^2: a\ge x^2+y^2\ge b\}$, $I=\big[\sqrt{b},\sqrt{a}\big]$ and 
$S=\{(x,y)\in\mathbb R^2: x^2+y^2=1\}$.

Then the map $f:S\times I\to A$, with
$$
f(s,t)=ts,
$$
is a homeomorphism.

Comment: Why $I=\big[\sqrt{b},\sqrt{a}\big]$ and not $I=\big[a,b]$? Because I want the product space of $S \times [a,b]$.

Comment: It would be $I=[a,b]$ if $A$ was defined as $A=\{(x,y): a^2\ge x^2+y^2\ge b^2\}$.